# PHP Create Local Variables From String

Tags: php, laravel, inheritance

Is there a way to create a variable inside an object from a string? for example:

```
class Whatever {

   public function createVariables() {
       $this["variable_name"] = 100;
   }

}
```

I want to dynamically create variables depending on a set of rules that are defined by a child class.

Comment: There are generally very few reasons where it's considered acceptable to use dynamically named variables (varvars), perhaps you could enlighten us on what you're trying to achieve (and what led you to your current solution/attempt) so someone might offer a better solution? If you're just filling a class-array (eg. `$this->my_array["foo"] = "bar";`) that's something totally different though.

Comment: @ccKep I am trying to implement my own version of laravel's Models but for apis etc. I want to be able to define variables on the fly like they do with the filable.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't used Laravel until now, do you have a link to an example / a resource that briefly describes your scenario? Sounds like [property overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) might be of use to you?

Comment: @ccKep https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent if you go down to mass assignment once it pulls the filable from the database you can then go object->variable_name

Comment: Looks like it's indeed realized through `__get` ([Model.php](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Model.php) Line 1219 which calls [Concerns/HasAttributes.php](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php)`::getAttribute`. Attributes are handled via [Concerns/GuardAttributes](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Concerns/GuardsAttributes.php).)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Whatever {

   public function createAttributes($attribute_name, $attribute_value = NULL) {
       $this->{$attribute_name} = $attribute_value;
   }
}
```

This is the way in PHP to add attributes dynamically, nothing related specially to laravel

Laravel also has a built-in way https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/v4.2.17/Eloquent/Model.php#L2551

Comment: No need for `{}`, you can do `$this->$attribute_name = $attribute_value;`

Comment: if the attribute does not exist it is right? As in creating them runtime.

Comment: @Thomas Nop, only if your variable would have some fancy name, eg. `$this->foo = 'baz'; $this->$this->foo = 'bar';`... In this case you'd need `$this->{$this->foo} = 'bar';`.

Comment: @ccKep I really don't get what you try to say. Can you explain?

Comment: @Thomas That was to answer your question in the comment regarding the need of `{}`. For simple names like `$attribute_name` they're not neccessary.

Answer (score -3):

```
class Whatever {

   protected $id;

   public function createAttributes($id) {
       $this->id = $id;
       return $this;
   }
}
```

You can call this variable as `$this->id` inside another functions